# What does ifelse do with NA values?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I've got code that does what I want.  I would, however, very much like to understand why it works one way and not the other.

I wanted to conditionally put new values into a new column, and wrote the following code:

```
test <- data.frame(Usual=c(1:3,NA,NA,4,5,7,15))

test$Active1 <- NA

test$Active1 <- ifelse(test[,"Usual"]==1|test[,"Usual"]==2|test[,"Usual"]==3,1,
                       ifelse(test[,"Usual"]==7,2,
                              ifelse(test[,"Usual"]==4|test[,"Usual"]==5|test[,"Usual"]==6|test[,"Usual"]==7,3,
                                     ifelse(is.na(test[,"Usual"]),"ROAR",":("))))
```

I put in the extra condition for is.na at the end, because I wasn't sure if it would get confused if I didn't do that.  But it doesn't replace the NAs with "ROAR" - why?

If I put the condition for is.na at the front of the ifelse, it does what I expected it to do:

```
test$Active2 <- NA
  test$Active2 <- ifelse(is.na(test[,"Usual"]),"ROAR",
                         ifelse(test[,"Usual"]==7,2,
                                ifelse(test[,"Usual"]==4|test[,"Usual"]==5|test[,"Usual"]==6|test[,"Usual"]==7,3,
                                       ifelse(test[,"Usual"]==1|test[,"Usual"]==2|test[,"Usual"]==3,1,":("))))
```

Why does it make a difference where it's put in the ifelse?  (I don't even need to use ifelse for this I know, but I was curious if it would look neater..)

Comment: Duuuude: just write a simple example and examine the output of an `ifelse` for inputs which are or aren't `NA` . Then all you have to do is realize that your top-level `ifelse` is sending either a `NA` or a value to the next `ifelse`, and so on.  Hey, it's not Rocket Surgery!

Comment: `%in%` would save you a lot of typing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page:

> yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.

In your first example, `ifelse(is.na())` is never evaluated for NA rows because it fails to evaluate at the first `ifelse` condition.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of question is most easily answered by simply typing `ifelse` in the R console, and the code used will be displayed.  Studying the code will tell you what it does with `NA`.

```
R > ifelse
function (test, yes, no) 
{
    if (is.atomic(test)) {
        if (typeof(test) != "logical") 
            storage.mode(test) <- "logical"
        if (length(test) == 1 && is.null(attributes(test))) {
            if (is.na(test)) 
                return(NA)
            else if (test) {
                if (length(yes) == 1 && is.null(attributes(yes))) 
                  return(yes)
            }
            else if (length(no) == 1 && is.null(attributes(no))) 
                return(no)
        }
    }
    else test <- if (isS4(test)) 
        as(test, "logical")
    else as.logical(test)
    ans <- test
    ok <- !(nas <- is.na(test))
    if (any(test[ok])) 
        ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & 
            ok]
    if (any(!test[ok])) 
        ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test & 
            ok]
    ans[nas] <- NA
    ans
}
<bytecode: 0x1018abad0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```